# Clear image with fade border

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics, cgcontext

I have two `UIImageView` with same frame. One `imageView` above second `imageView` now I'm erasing upper `imageView` using [Core Graphics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/coregraphics/reference/coregraphics_framework/_index.html). My problem is that the border of eraser is very sharp I want faded border i.e. after erasing the upper image should match the lower one's pallet. See below example -  
[image][image]

I used these two images and below is result - 
[image] 
As you can see in this image eraser's border is very sharp. I want to make it faded out like in the middle it should be dark then light then more light and so on i.e. we cant see the width and end of brush. And here is my - [My Sample Code](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/74641080/FaceSwitching.zip) 
 Let me know if my question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a png image like brush (dark in the middle and light in the corner) and draw the image over your image like this.

```
        [eraser drawAtPoint:location blendMode:kCGBlendModeDestinationOut alpha:1];
```

Comment: Which color of png image because color is not static I have used `colorWithImagePattern:` for eraser color ....

Comment: I have made some changes to your project. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/661y3vvjiklpz6n/8cHvcYxQ3A. Is that what you want?

Comment: Awesome answer dude .... I will accept it tomorrow I'm just waiting for alternative solutions :)  Great Answer !!

Comment: Please share the project , No file Found is what i get!! :(